# Google Script to grab values in a column and compares those to parameter with if/else statement

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create an app script that you can type in the name and username of an individual and select various dates associated with their training. I'm nearly done with the project but one piece of script is giving me issues. What the script is supposed to do is take the User Name I've entered into the app and see if that value already exists in column L of the archive. If the value exists then it should return an alert with a YES_NO option and depending on what is selected it will either cancel the import or continue on and import the username to the sheet.

I've been trying to figure out this script for about 5 days and cannot figure it out. I've tried pretty much everything I can think of.  Here's the code. The Username already exists in Cell L3 of the Archive.

```
function postApp(e)
{
  var usern = e.parameter.userN;
  var name1 = e.parameter.name;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tM = sheet.getSheetByName('Archive');
  var tR = tM.getLastRow()-1;
  var tC = tM.getLastColumn();
  var tD = tM.getRange("L3").getValues();
    if(tD == usern )
    {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
      var result = ui.alert('Wait', 'The Username you are trying to use has already been archived. Would you still like to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
     if (result == ui.Button.Yes) {
  // User clicked "Yes".
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Error Report Has Been Updated', 'UPDATE ERRORS',3);
      var date = new Date();
      var d = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy');

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('SyNERGY');
      var lR = s.getLastRow()+1;
      var lC = s.getLastColumn();

      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var name = e.parameter.name;
      var user = e.parameter.userN;
      var team = e.parameter.team;
      var hire = e.parameter.hire;

    ////////////////////////////
      // CREATE REPORT CARD

  genReportCard(name, team, hire, app, user);

   s.getRange(lR,12).setValue([[user]]).setNumberFormat(';;;');
   s.getRange(lR,12).setValue(user.toString().toLowerCase());
   s.getRange(lR,11).setValue('SyN');
  ///////////////////////////////////////////
///////////Close after complete////////////
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert("Specialist Created!");

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.close();
    return app;
}else {
     // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Import Canceled');
}

}else{
  var date = new Date();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 
'M/d/yyyy');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('SyNERGY');
  var lR = s.getLastRow()+1;
  var lC = s.getLastColumn();

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var name = e.parameter.name;
  var user = e.parameter.userN;
  var team = e.parameter.team;
  var hire = e.parameter.hire;

  ////////////////////////////
  // CREATE REPORT CARD

  genReportCard(name, team, hire, app, user);

   s.getRange(lR,12).setValue([[user]]).setNumberFormat(';;;');
   s.getRange(lR,12).setValue(user.toString().toLowerCase());
   s.getRange(lR,11).setValue('SyN');
  ///////////////////////////////////////////
///////////Close after complete////////////
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert("Specialist Created!");

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.close();
    return app;

 }
}
```

This script Works as long as I am referencing One Cell so `tM.getRange("L3").getValues();` Works. However, As soon as I change that to `tM.getRange("L3:L").getValues();` it does not recognize the value exists within the range and returns the else portion of the code.

I have also tried a loop for the top section that is giving me issues but the same thing is happening. As soon as I try to find a value within the column rather than a specific cell it won't work. Here is what it looks like with the loop.

```
    function postApp(e)
{
  var usern = e.parameter.userN;
  var name1 = e.parameter.name;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tM = sheet.getSheetByName('Archive');
  var tR = tM.getLastRow()-1;
  var tC = tM.getLastColumn();
  var tD = tM.getDataRange().getValues();
   for(var i = 0; i<tD.length; i++){
    if(tD[i][11] == usern )
    {
```

If anyone can figure out what i'm doing wrong or why it's not working as soon as I reference the entire column any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: getValues returns an array of arrays even it it's a column only

Comment: Sorry, I started teaching myself google script in June so i'm not 100% familiar with all of the terminology. What exactly are you suggesting?